# Rogue DHCP in My network

Tags: windows

My network is 172.19.20.1, but some of the computers in the network occasionally pick 192.168.200.1 which stops the user from using a major application in the company. what do I do to Identify the devices dishing our this ip in my network since I can ping it. Kindly help.

Comment: Depending on your switch model(s), you may be able to use a built-in feature to stop the problem, e.g. Cisco has features such as [IP DHCP Snooping](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/general/Test/dwerblo/broken_guide/snoodhcp.html) and other features to mitigate such problems.

Answer (score 8):

A fairly easy three-step process:

- Find the MAC of the offending DHCP server. You should be able to find it on a computer that's assigned the wrong IP address, ping the DHCP server and then look in the MAC table
- Use the address tables in the switches on the LAN to find the physical port to which the offending server is connected
- Follow the cable coming out of the port on the switch and find the physical computer

Comment: If it doesn't respond to ping you can just renew the ip-address to achieve the refresh of the MAC table. In order to look in the MAC table: The command is "arp -a" (on Windows, Linux and MacOS) and requires admin/sudo-rights.

Comment: I remember the fun of solving this with only unmanaged switches. We managed to identify the device by talking to it and followed every wire until we found it. It got unplugged.